# Ubuntu 12.04.5 as full download?

Tags: 12.04

If i'm right 12.04.5 is available as from today. However, I don't see a download for the (full) version, does this become available (or not), or can one only upgrade to 12.04.5 from 12.04.4?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the "full" version? Point releases are just security updates up to date.

Comment: an iso download just as for 12.04.4, 14.04.1 LTS...

Answer (score 5):

It's available on the following URL:

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.5/

As ever, these are just new CDs with all the updates and [the latest hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#A12.04.5_.2B-_14.04_Hardware_Enablement_Stack_Policies_and_Procedures) pre-installed. Just install your updates (and the Trusty HWE stack) and you'll be on 12.04.5:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty
```

If you're ever in the situation where you're *close* to a release and want the latest installer, you can always use a daily. In this case the [precise/daily image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/precise/daily/current/) would have given you practically the same thing as the final (if not exactly the same thing) just with added testing. Just note that it would technically be a pre-release so all the normal warnings apply.

And note that 12.04.5 is too big for a normal 703MB CD. You'll either need a super-extended CD or a DVD or USB stick.

Comment: I have a new machine to install so i thought i wait for the 12.04.5 release.

Comment: ok thanks i downloaded already it in the mean time